# How to test /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, hosts

What's the best way to confirm that your /etc/hosts file is mapping a hostname to the correct IP address?

Using a tool like `dig` queries an external DNS directly, bypassing the hosts file.

Comment: hosts files do not map domains....them map specific hostnames to IP addresses.

Comment: @mdpc I edited it to reflect that.  Basically the same question though, I was just looking for a way to verify the hosts file entry is working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tried this out and it seems to work as expected:

`echo "1.2.3.4    facebook.com" >> /etc/hosts`

Then I ran:

```
$ getent ahosts facebook.com
1.2.3.4         STREAM facebook.com
1.2.3.4         DGRAM  
1.2.3.4         RA
```

Comment: looks good, thanks!  I also found that ping works: `ping facebook.com`
outputs:
`PING facebook.com (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.`

Answer (score 5):

I found `gethostip` which accepts either hostname or IP and also has options suitable to print out exactly what you need.

```
$ gethostip -d facebook
1.2.3.4
```

Comment: On Debian `gethostip` is not installed by default. Use `sudo apt install syslinux-utils`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'ping' command to check the values added in /etc/hosts are working fine or not.

```
echo "1.1.1.1   abc.com" >> /etc/hosts
ping abc.com
```